# Table within Div within Div

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I have a slight issue that I have not been able to solve. I require to have a web page that comprises of a header(OuterHeader), a footer(OuterFooter) and a content. Within the Content I require another header(InnerHeader) and footer(InnerFooter) as well as a table that is scroll-able when covered by the innerFooter.

The outerHeader and outerFooter will be a constant size along with the innerHeader and InnerFooter. This all needs to work with a page that can be size adjustable.

So far this is what I have on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvLLbs32/

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div name="OuterHeader" id="OuterHeader"> 
        <p>This is the OuterHeader.</p> 
    </div>
    <div name="Content" id="Content"> 
            <div name="InnerHeader" id="InnerHeader"> 
                <p>This is the InnerHeader.</p> 
            </div>
            <div name="Wrapper" id="Wrapper">
                <div name="TableDiv" id="TableDiv">
                    <table name="Table" id="Table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>******</td>
                            <td>******</td> 
                            <td>******</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td> 
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>        
                            <td>80</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td> 
                            <td>50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td> 
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>        
                            <td>80</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td> 
                            <td>50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td> 
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>        
                            <td>80</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td> 
                            <td>50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td> 
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>Doe</td>        
                            <td>80</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jill</td>
                            <td>Smith</td> 
                            <td>50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Eve</td>
                            <td>Jackson</td> 
                            <td>94</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>******</td>
                            <td>******</td> 
                            <td>******</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div name="InnerFooter" id="InnerFooter"> 
                <p>This is the InnerFooter.</p> 
            </div>
    </div>
    <div name="OuterFooter" id="OuterFooter"> 
        <p>This is the OuterFooter.</p> 
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#OuterHeader {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0px;
    height : 100px;
    width : 100%;
    overflow: hidden;   
    z-index : 1;
}

#InnerHeader {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: yellow;
    height : 100px;
    width : 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Content {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: orange;
    width : 100%;
    bottom:200px;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#InnerFooter {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0px;
    height : 100px;
    width : 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#OuterFooter {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: blue;
    bottom : 0px;
    height : 100px;
    width : 100%;
}

#Wrapper{
    position: absolute; /* absolute*/
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#TableDiv{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#Table{
    width:100%; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}

#Table td{ 
    padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
}

#Table tr{
    background: #b8d1f3;
}

#Table tr td:nth-child(odd){ 
    background: #b8d1f3;
}

#Table tr td:nth-child(even){
    background: #dae5f4;
}
```

The colours might be bad, but it helps to differentiate the different Divs.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you describe the difference between what you want to get and what you are getting? In other words, what is the problem that made you come here. Also, currently this question is "here's my code, please fix it". It's better when you try to make a [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/) that shows just the problem and nothing else, this will often help you fix your own problem and when it doesn't, it isolates the problem so people can help you better.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. What I was getting is that the table would only be scroll-able when it reached the outerfooter. I wasn't able to restrict the table at the innerfooter.

What I needed was for the table to be restricted within the innerheader and innerfooter. But it seems that @Pete 's answer seems to fix that issue for me.

Comment: Also thank you @Jasper for noting me about that, it will allow my questions to be more efficient in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the following html and styles:

```css
body, html {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#table .row {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
#table #content {
    height:100%;
}
#outer-header {
    background:red
}
#inner-header {
    background:yellow
}
#inner-footer {
    background:green
}
#outer-footer {
    background:blue
}
#TableDiv {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#Table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#Table td {
    padding:7px;
    border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
}
#Table tr {
    background: #b8d1f3;
}
#Table tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #b8d1f3;
}
#Table tr td:nth-child(even) {
    background: #dae5f4;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="table">
        <div id="outer-header" class="row">outer-header</div>
        <div id="inner-header" class="row">inner-header</div>
        <div id="content" class="row">
            <div name="TableDiv" id="TableDiv">
                <table name="Table" id="Table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>******</td>
                        <td>******</td>
                        <td>******</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John</td>
                        <td>Doe</td>
                        <td>80</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jill</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eve</td>
                        <td>Jackson</td>
                        <td>94</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>******</td>
                        <td>******</td>
                        <td>******</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="inner-footer" class="row">inner-footer</div>
        <div id="outer-footer" class="row">outer-footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle so you can see it in a high window](http://jsfiddle.net/hvLLbs32/2/)

If you want the footer to be pushed off the bottom if the content is too long, rather than have the content section scroll, then just remove the `#TableDiv` styles

Comment: Thank you @Pete for you quick and swift response. Your answer seems to solve my issue quite effectively. I also wish I could upvote your answer but sadly I still don't have enough reputation to do so yet (The joys of not being a regular user here)

Comment: Hi Dean, if this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick below the voting buttons.  Thanks, and glad to help